# Probably a really dumb MassTransit misunderstanding

Tags: msmq, masstransit

I'm a new to MassTransit and one thing I don't understand is this:

How do you create a bus between multiple .net ServiceBuses?

Take this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IConsumer>());

        Console.WriteLine("Starting Buses!");

        var bus1 = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/bus1");
            sbc.Subscribe(s => s.LoadFrom(container));

        });

        var bus2 = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/bus2");

            sbc.Subscribe(s => s.LoadFrom(container));
        });

        bus1.Publish(new TestMsg() { Name = "Hello Matt!" });

        Console.WriteLine("Sent Message");

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
public class TestMsg
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestMsgConsumer : Consumes<TestMsg>.All, IBusService
{
    private IServiceBus bus;

    public void Consume(TestMsg message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got message on " + this.Context().Endpoint.Address);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (bus != null)
            bus.Dispose();
    }

    public void Start(IServiceBus bus)
    {
        this.bus = bus;
    }

    public void Stop()
    {

    }

}
```

I would expect the "Got message on ..." to show up twice, since I have two buses. However, I only get one. Obviously there is some step that ties these two Bus instances to the same logical bus I'm not understanding what that is. I can't point them at the same queue name since, again, only one would get the message.

Thanks!

**EDIT/SOLUTION**:

I got some help from the MT Google Groups and they got me straightened away quickly... this wasn't working as expected because I didn't have the multicast bits of MSMQ installed. Got those installed and it worked as expected.

Comment: I believe it may be a timing issue. Did you try putting in a sleep between `ServiceBusFactory.New` and `bus1.Publish`.

Comment: Nope, if I put a Thread.Sleep in there to make sure the bus is up and running it still doesn't get a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the original post for the answer, but it basically came down to not having the Multicast bits of MSMQ installed. Put those in and all works as expected.